# RxJava: merging observables on different threads

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2

I need to merge two observables running on different threads. Sample code is

```
val obs1 = Observable
    .create<Int> { emitter ->
        emitter.onNext(1)
        emitter.onComplete()
    }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())

val obs2 = Observable.just(2)

val obs = Observable
    .just(1, 2)
    .flatMap {
        Observable.merge(
            Observable.just(it).filter { it == 1 }.flatMap { obs1 },
            Observable.just(it).filter { it == 2 }.flatMap { obs2 }
        )
    }
    .serialize()

obs.blockingSubscribe(::println)
```

Expecting output as `1, 2`, sometime get it `2, 1`.
It seems `serialize()` doesn't help.
How can I achieve right emission order - `1, 2`?

Answer (score 0):

Have found proper solution quickly :)

```
val obs = Observable
    .just(1, 2)
    .concatMap {
        if (it == 1) obs1 else obs2
    }
```

Comment: The question mentions `merge`, but merging in Rx does not take the order into consideration. But judging from this it looks like the order IS important. Why don't you just ```Observable.concat(obs1, obs2)```?

Comment: Is just a simplified examle of my case. You right, it's ok to use `Observable.concat` also.